# Why not use an array of pointers to optimize linked list but use skip list?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, lookup, skip-lists

Recently I was learning about the skip list, and I've learned that it is designed to speed up the lookup of linked list. But I am wondering why not use a data structure which adds an array of pointers of all nodes based on the structure of the linked list ? For a list of `2^n` nodes, if each levels we have half of the number of pointers of the lower level we will add `2^n-1` ponters, it's almost the same number of adding a list of pointers of each nodes, and at the same time it's O(1) to access by index.

There must be some reasons not to implement my idea, can anyone tell me?

Comment: Ho do you update the array of pointers (which is basically standard array) when new element shows up?

Comment: Why do you think your proposed data structure allows random access in O(1) time?

Comment: The idea is similar to databases, which are typically sorted by a primary key but have tier arrays of keys to speed up searching by key value. For example a first level key to record index map for every 256 records. There may be a second level key to first level index for every 256 1st level entries. There may be a third level, depending on the size of a database. The skip list is a similar idea, and you could have a skip list to a skip list to a linked list.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more about what these arrays are and how they'd be represented?

Comment: @kaya3 If you want to access the nth node, just access the nth element of the array to get its pointer

Comment: @libik The insertion of new element performs exactly like what a linked list and an array does, of which the time complexity are `O(1)` and `O(n)` respectively.

Comment: If you have an array containing references to every node, then it's hardly a linked list, is it? That would be an arraylist. If you are going to have an array long enough to contain one thing per list item, the array might as well store the list items directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A skip list offers average performance of `O(log(n))` to read, insert, update and delete the element at any index.

Your array of pointers idea offers average performance of `O(1)`, `O(n)`, `O(1)` and `O(n)` for the same operations.  Admittedly with a good constant on the `O(n)` operations, but still that is how it scales.

Both data structures are used in practice.  They are just used for different situations.

Comment: Thank you, I just looked up for the mechanism of rebuild the index while adding an element and realize that it is `O(log(n))`. Can you give an example of the array of pointers idea used in practice?

Comment: Arrays of pointers are used all over the place.  To pick a completely random example, line 26 of https://docs.huihoo.com/doxygen/linux/kernel/3.7/fdtable_8h_source.html declares that `fd` in `fd_table` is a pointer to an array of pointers to file descriptor objects.